# Apache2 - point all subages to default directory /www/html

Tags: apache, server, web-applications, webserver

I want my application show different data according the keyword they put in url path behind the slash `/` e.g. `www.url.com/keyword`. I am handling it in javascript.

But I want my apache to point all the `subpages` to exactly one default directory which is `/www/html` - the default one.

Now it doesn't work, when I tryit with different `/keywords` apache shows me `Not Found`.

Can you help me what apache configuration should be changed ? I am using default configuration now, even without SSL cert.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this with using Aliases.

by adding to general apache2.conf

```
Alias /keyword /var/www/html
```